# Get second column of line with certain text from command output directly

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to extract the text in second column of multiple line command output.

The command shows an output like this.

```
Nginx configuration  wp basic (enabled) 
PHP Version      7.0    
HHVM             disabled    
SSL          enabled    
SSL PROVIDER             Lets Encrypt    
SSL EXPIRY DATE          Wed Apr 11 06:29:29 UTC 2018

access_log       /var/www/website.com/logs/access.log    
error_log        /var/www/website.com/logs/error.log    
Webroot          /var/www/website.com    
DB_NAME          certainDBName    
DB_USER          certainDBUser    
DB_PASS          passwordString
```

I want to read the `DB_PASS` line from command output and extract the `passwordString` to a variable, directly from my first command output without writing to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With single **`awk`** command:

```
pass_str=$(awk '/^DB_PASS/{ print $2; exit }' file)
```

---

```
$ echo "$pass_str" 
passwordString
```

Comment: Instead of file, how can i use a command output as an input parameter for awk command? Its only for avoid having to write a file.

Comment: @eifersucht, by this scheme: `pass_str=$(awk '/^DB_PASS/{ print $2; exit }' <(some_command))`

Comment: This is the perfect answer for my question

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it using `awk`

```
awk '$1=="DB_PASS" { print $2 }' test.log > output.txt
```

This means print column 2 in the row where column 1 is equals to "DB_PASS" assuming your result is in a `test.log` file

Comment: +1 Hmmm, I believe this is the most ideal way of doing it :-)  But the op doesn't wish the result to be written to a file. Instead you should use the command substitution `$()` feature to write the results into a variable.

Comment: Yes but I think it can be easily turned in a command that take input from a pipe and save it to a variable, I am giving an idea not coding for you guys :)

Comment: Can i use this command using my info command as an input on the fly? Instead of writing the first output to a file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` as proposed by @RomanPerekhrest or use `sed`

```
sed -n 's/DB_PASS \(.*\)/\1/p' <youfile>
```

Comment: This will work, but as You and I know this is the hard way of doing it. The `awk` is better suited for this kind of job. You might want to add a `--` after the `-n` so that you could also accept the filenames starting with dashes like `-my-file`.

Comment: @sjsam hehe.. yes, we do. It was the first that came to my mind answer. I left the answer because it's always good to see more than one solution